# Unable to see css for hover state

Tags: css

I have a project I've taken over that is quite large.

I'm trying to update the nav so it goes end to end on the page.

Even though I have it at:

```
width:100%;
left:0;
right:0;
```

When I hover over a menu item and the menu pops up, I can see that it only spans 80% of the page. So there is something else wrapping it.

How do I inspect an element that only appears when you hover over it?

If I right click in Chrome, the hover state disappears...

Any thoughts?

Comment: is it possible to add some code? it helps you get a better answer.

Comment: That's the problem. There is a lot of styles and I'm trying to figure out which one I should be looking at by inspecting the element. But I'm not sure how to get google tools element inspector to capture information for something that is in a hover state. When I try to right click to inspect it, it goes away.

Comment: can you add a Live link where we can watch the error or issue.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not public.

Comment: so you should be try to make a video or some images about your issue or error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the element you want to check.

then right click on the element in de inspector then you will see some options one of them ':hover' click that.

Now the hover state is active on the selected element.

[image]